# Rails - Creating forms with a triple join using a dropdown and multi-select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have 4 models(nothing here is set in stone. If there is another way to do this that is fine)

```
Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :member_to_clubs
  has_many :clubs, through :member_to_clubs
  has_many :jobs, through :member_to_clubs
end

Class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Class MemberToClub < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Members can be in multiple clubs. Members can have multiple jobs in clubs(same person can be president, treasurer, etc.).

What would be the best form/controller setup to create these in a single form? My ideal scenario would be to have a form that looks something like the following and I have a semi-working implementation.

[image: sample form]

Clubs are picked out of a dropdown and then the jobs are assigned from a multi-select. Is there a "rails way" of doing this? I tried doing a completely custom implementation where the form sends the following params

```
"member"=>{"Name"=>"John Smith", "member_to_clubs_attributes"=>{"1582563582187"=>{"club_id"=>"4", "job_id"=>["1", "2"], "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1582563587159"=>{"club_id"=>"3", "job_id"=>["4"], "_destroy"=>"false"}}}
```

and I have a private method in the controller that iterates over the `member_to_club_attributes` and then the `job_id` array and creates all the necessary `MemberToClub` models(there is other stuff in there too about editing existing `MemberToClub` instances but suffice it to say that it works). The issue there is that when I go back in to edit a user with existing `MemberToClub` instances, the previous example looks like this
[image]

I guess my questions are, is there a better model/association setup that I can do here, and given the above scenarios what is the most "rails way" of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help